# C# disable program from writing to windows event viewer

Tags: c#, event-viewer

i have made an example program which accesses my location when a button is clicked and automatically an icon pops up in the bottom right of my screen to say my location has recently been accessed (event viewer). The only thing i could find that says it prevents this is below but even that doesnt work. Im not even sure its possibile, mabye i have to do something in the registry? i dont think i can disable event viewer as a whole. any help is appriciated

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [ServiceProcessDescriptionAttribute("SBAutoLog")]

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoLog = false; //suppose to disable writing to event viewer
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //gets my location
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher GEOWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750);
        GEOWatcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        GeoCoordinate Coordinates = GEOWatcher.Position.Location;
        GEOWatcher.Dispose();
    }

    public static bool AutoLog { get; set; }
}
```

Even if it still writes to the event viewer but doesnt have to pop up will do, thanks again

Comment: Form doesnt have a property AutoLog. AutoLog belongs to ServiceBase. This class is a Form class.

Comment: do you know how i would fix it?